# return mongoose document if virtual populated field length greater then 0

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

this is typegoose schema, there are two properties named as **productSellers**, **adsSellers** and both are **virtual**.

```
Product.find().populate(['productSellers', 'adsSellers']);

export class Product  {
      static readonly collectionName = 'Products';

      @arrayProp({
        justOne: false,
        ref: 'ProductSeller', 
        foreignField: 'product', 
        localField: '_id', 

      })
      productSellers: Ref<ProductSeller>[];

      @arrayProp({
        ref: 'ProductSeller', 
        foreignField: 'product', 
        localField: '_id', 
        count: true,
      })
      productSellerCount: Ref<ProductSeller>[];

      @arrayProp({
        justOne: false,
        ref: 'Adpost', 
        foreignField: 'product', 
        localField: '_id', 
      })
      adsSellers: Ref<Adpost>[];

      static get model() {
        return getModelForClass(Product);
      }

      static get modelName() {
        return this.model.modelName;
      }

      static get schema() {
        return buildSchema(Product);
      }
    }
```

- i want to query in that way in which if (adsSellers.length >0 || productSellers.length>0) then it will return **product** otherwise not

Comment: This question needs to be reworded to a sentence format to be made more clear.

Comment: check now I have changed the words